# Diagram of Tensho kata?

Tags: karate, forms

I'd like to locate a diagram or other documentation of the Tensho kata. There are some videos available (many of which are very helpful) but I'd like to obtain a printed description of the form if possible. I understand that the fluid motions of the form makes it difficult to capture this in perfection but I'd like to find something that would serve as a mental hint for teaching and for my own ongoing study of the form.

#### Prior Research Examples

Here are a few of the sites I've checked as a result of multiple Google searches like "tensho kata diagram":

- http://www.ggodkarate.com/Documents/SANCHIN%20KATA.pdf
- http://www.uchinadi-kan.org/kata/katalist.html
- http://ymaa.com/files/B0845SamplePages.pdf
- http://www.guardiandojo.com/Kyokushin/Katas.aspx
- http://www.dragonslist.com/threads/the-rokkishu-tensho-bubishi-connection.165/
- http://www.shorekarate.co.nz/kata/tensho.html (like the footwork diagrams)

I've also searched MA.SA for "tensho" with no results.

Comment: [Does these images help?](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Tensho+kata&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=TaKwUcrkFvGK4gT-_IGwDw&ved=0CFgQsAQ&biw=1918&bih=971#imgrc=_)...

Comment: Yes. In reference to karate. Added the tag. Thanks.

Comment: @Sardathrion, thanks for the link. I did search Google with no success. My error in not searching GI first. This link led to several diagrams/images of Tensho. Submit as an answer and I will accept. Thx.

Comment: You are welcome but I shall not write an answer as some prior research is a prerequisite of the site.

Comment: @Sardathrion I believe I see your logic. +1 for sticking so fiercely to "the code". :) Some may contend that the statement in the question details "There are some videos available" would imply previous research and discovery. However, I can see the need for some improvement to those details to assure the prerequisites were met. Hopefully this latest edit allows you to post your answer.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I did not downvote because the question is valid -- even more so since you added lots of information to it!  It has a very useful answer (yours) and will be great for future readers so really, I should upvote it all and shut up.  ^_~  Done on both counts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Kyokushin-kan Australia website](http://www.kyokushinkan-australia.com/kyokushin-kata.html) has this [diagram of Tensho](http://www.kyokushinkan-australia.com/uploads/1/8/0/0/18009363/5367939.jpg):

[image]

Comment: May I suggest a bigger version of this image: http://www.kyokushinkan-australia.com/uploads/1/8/0/0/18009363/5367939_orig.jpg

Answer (score 2):

After having done a little research on Tensho, I'm fairly certain that anything printed will not be useful without a massive amount of knowledge.
To that end, I'd rather point you towards [Higaonna-sensei's performance of Tensho](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiIv3zDJc-I).

In addition, this video about a two-person drill on [Tensho](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34e77CtQjVc) is rather informative as far as what kind of energy/direction you are looking for in the Tensho movements.

This might be helpful in creating notes for teaching.

Comment: Although these video clips are not the diagrams and text descriptions sought for in the question, I believe these are invaluable resources for anyone studying the Tensho kata. Too bad we do not have video of all the masters and their kata. Love the two-person drill video. Amazing how much knowledge is encapsulated in this form. Thx.

Comment: Also difficult to document ibuki on paper.

Answer (score 0):

A diagram and written description is in Robert Trias' "Pinnacle of Karate" book, but you'll need to drop some coin on that.