# Author of Kata Diagrams

Tags: karate, forms

Does anyone know who has made these diagrams?

[image]
[image]

I reckon that it was a published in German, so the author is probably from Germany.

Comment: It hasn't helped so far, but we've had [this diagram](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/2019/1780) before.

Comment: Thanks, but why is an Australian website using a German diagram? (perhaps because it is still helpful)